# Loading pickle in R

Tags: python, r, pickle

I am trying to load a pickle object in R, using the following process found online.

First, I create a Python file called: "pickle_reader.py":

```py
import pandas as pd
def read_pickle_file(file):
    pickle_data = pd.read_pickle(file)
    return pickle_data
```

Then, I run the following R code:

```
install.packages('reticulate')

require("reticulate")

source_python("pickle_reader.py")
pickle_data <- read_pickle_file("pathname")
```

but I get an error that says:

> Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :
> ImportError: No module named pandas

N.B. I tried installing pandas again but this doesn't change the issue.

Do you know how should I proceed?

Comment: Does your python script work when you use it without R? Do you have pandas installed? Are you sure you even need panas to read the pickle?

Answer (score 4):

I find this to be a much more straight forward method than making a new `.py` file. In an R code chunk do:

```
library(reticulate)

pd <- import("pandas")

x <- pd$read_pickle("file.pickle")
```

Comment: How do you then read the data into proper arrays in R? I can get the pickle, but I can't open it. ```pickle_data``` is a named list, each of which contains a 4D array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a python package into a different environment, which in this case is R, you must search how to install python packages in R. In this case, looking at the [CRAN webpage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/python_packages.html) you can see that in order to install pandas in the environment of R you need the command *py_install('pandas')*.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pandas installed. I suggest using conda environment. I read the pickle applying below steps:

- Create conda environment and install necessary packages.
- Then in R, you can set the right python (which is python in your conda env)

```
    Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "~/anaconda3/envs/your_env/bin/python")

    library(reticulate)
```

You can check with `py_config()`

- Now you can read your pickle files in R,

```
    
    loadData = function(file_path){
      require("reticulate")
      source_python("pickle_reader.py")
      
      pd <- import("pandas")
      return (pd$read_pickle(file_path))
    }

    features = loadData(features_path)
```