Opening python .pkl files in Rstudio
I am trying in Rstudio to open .pkl files generated by Python.
For this, I follow this instruction:
https://forum.posit.co/t/opening-a-pickle-file-in-r-studio/54191/2
But there I am stuck at this line:
py_install("pickle") # Not sure this line is needed - pickle may be built-in

Because Rstudio responds with:
> py_install("pickle") # Not sure this line is needed - pickle may be built-in
Using virtual environment '/Users/la/.venv' ...
+ /Users/la/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-user pickle
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle
Error: Error installing package(s): 'pickle'

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Have you tried simply not using that line?

Not sure if you should follow instructions including such comments. Rather check answers from linked SO thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095243/646761
